# How to import an AWS Managed Lambda Layer in Terrafrom

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-lambda-layers

AWS manages a layer called AWSDataWrangler-Python38.  How do I import it into my Terraform Code.  I tried using the Layer Module

```
resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "lambda_layer" {
  layer_name = "AWSDataWrangler-Python39"
  compatible_runtimes = ["python3.9"]
}
```

It throws an error to specify filename, but there is no file for this layer since it is managed by AWS and it is not a custom layer

Comment: Why do you want to import AWS Lambda layer to your state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not import a resource which is not managed by you.

Since this is a layer managed by AWS, there is a public list with all the ARN numbers available for this layer: https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/layers.html

If you want to use this layer for a Lambda in your Terraform code, you will have to take an ARN from this list and simply hard-code it (or provide it externally with a variable). For example:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  function_name    = "MyFunction"
  ...

  layers = [
    "arn:aws:lambda:${var.region}:336392948345:layer:AWSDataWrangler-Python39:6"
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying, I did this and it complained that ARN is not valid, I replaced it with my account number

Comment: You don't want to replace it with your account number. The account number in the ARN is the number of an account managed by AWS. You need to replace the region only. The layer should be publicly available for anyone to use.

Comment: ok let me try, thanks

Comment: Also, you may want to check if your region has the version of the layer from the end (`:6`). You can see this in the link I provided. Check which is the latest version provided for your region, it might not be 6.

Comment: If this is publicly accessible, why am I getting access denied, do I have configure some permissions

Comment: Apparently, the ARNs are not working for some versions. I tried for `us-east-1` the ARN of `arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:336392948345:layer:AWSDataWrangler-Python39:5` and it works. Version 6 (as it on the site) is not working or it was not published yet.